# python write in file list of list with different separator

Tags: python, list

I have a list of list like that :

```
liste = [["1-2","3-4"],["5-6"]]
```

I would like to write in a file like that :

```
1-2,3-4|5,6
```

I try this :

```
for l in liste:
    sortie.write(",".join(l)+"|")
```

but it writes:

```
1-2,3-4|5,6|
```

How can I delete (or don't write) the last pipe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list comprehension to join your lists in one `.write()` call:

```
sortie.write('|'.join([','.join(l) for l in liste]))
```

This replaces your `for` loop over `liste`.

Demo:

```
>>> liste = [["1-2","3-4"],["5-6"]]
>>> '|'.join([','.join(l) for l in liste])
'1-2,3-4|5-6'
```

Comment: that's neat, I'm afraid I don't understand why the first part of the nesting works: `[','.join(l) for l in liste]` . When i see this the result I expect is `['1-2,3-4,5-6']` nor do I get why it doesn't work, in the interpreter, when I omit the []  `','.join(l) for l in liste`

Comment: @Dee: there are nested lists; each list object in `liste` needs joining first (using `','`), before joining those results with `'|'`.

Comment: yes, the logic I grasp, I'm failing to see how the result is reached though. weird I know. I think looking at it again now, if I imagine the removal of the quotes as more fundamental I start to see the elements coming together the way they appropriately do, rather than the commas being the key - even though they are the key. my mind block, must be some childhood trauma inhibiting me ;)

Answer (score 1):

Nested joins:

```
s = '|'.join(','.join(l) for l in liste)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> lines = []
>>> for line in liste:
...     lines.append(','.join(map(str, line)))
... 
>>> print '|'.join(lines)
1-2,3-4|5-6
>>>
```